# Posting all selected rows using Grid.Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have successfully implemended a new Index view to my application will will render all outstanding emails to a gridview which features a checkbox for each row.

My intention now is to send an email which will include details of each record selected to a designated recipient.

Once a record has been selected and the details mailed for that record, I will flag that row as 'Emailed' and filter all emailed rows out in my controller before passing the list to the view.

I am a little confused as to how I make my submit button capture all selected records that have been checked and post the entire page back to my controller where I can do my email related stuff.

Here's what I have so far, I don't think I have wired up the submit button correctly to the gridview:

```
@using GridMvc.Html

@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
           {
               columns.Add()
                .Encoded(false)
                .Sanitized(false)
                .Titled("Send Email?")
                .SetWidth(30)                
                .RenderValueAs(o => Html.CheckBox("checked", false));

               columns.Add(a => a.Id).Titled("Id").SetWidth(110);

               columns.Add(a => a.AddressLineOneOld).Titled("Old Address")
                   .RenderValueAs(a => a.AddressLineOneOld + " " +
                                  a.AddressLineTwoOld + " " + 
                                  a.AddressLineThreeOld + " " +                                  
                                  a.AddressLineFiveOld);

               columns.Add(a => a.PostcodeOld).Titled("Old Postcode").Sortable(true);

               columns.Add(a => a.AddressLineOneNew).Titled("New Address")
                   .RenderValueAs(a => a.AddressLineOneNew + " " +
                                  a.AddressLineTwoNew + " " +
                                  a.AddressLineThreeNew + " " +                                  
                                  a.AddressLineFiveNew);

               columns.Add(a => a.PostcodeNew).Titled("New Postcode").Sortable(true);
               columns.Add(a => a.Emailed).Sortable(true);

           }).WithPaging(20)

<br />

<div style="float:right;">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EmailManager", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "frm", id = "frm" }))
{
        <input id="btnSendEmailForSelected" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Email Selected" class="btn btn-default" />
}
</div>
```

How do I post all selected rows back to the controller?

Comment: check this article for submitting selected row in mvc http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/706728/ASP-NET-MVC-Display-an-HTML-Table-with-Checkboxes

Comment: @SherifAhmed so you think I should use a table instead of a gridview, is this not achievable using Grid.Mvc?

Comment: not you can achieve it throw the Grid.Mvc but you will use FormCollection to get the selected Values like the answer I will write  right now below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it this line `Html.CheckBox("checked", false)` add a unique name add the value for the checkbox to the Id or the unique key you have as below

```
Html.CheckBox("checked", false, new {name = "selectedAddressesIds", value = "UNIQUE_KEY_HERE"})
```

and in the action method try the following, you must write your action method to have `FormCollection`

```
var selectedIds = form.GetValues("selectedAddressesIds");
if (selectedIds != null)
{
    foreach (var id in selectedIds)
    {
      // do what you want with the selected id.
    }
}
```

Comment: The only item in my form collection object is the submit button, are you sure I don't have to do something with the @using (Html.BeginForm that I have at the bottom of the page, the opening and closing braces are only around the button, the grid view is external to this but I cant seem to get it to wrap around the grid?

Comment: is there a problem to put the grid inside of the form

Comment: Scroll down my code snippet and look where the Html.BeginForm starts and ends, I think this is why when I post I cant see the grid data

Comment: the only thing in the collection is the button itself, no grid

Comment: you have to put the grid inside your form to post it back to the action method with the selected ids

Comment: OK I am now seeing the record in the grid, however selectedIds is always null

Comment: replace "UNIQUE_KEY_HERE" with a.Id to put all the id or each model

Comment: Yeh i got that, its EmailId in my case but its not picking it up